# Is it possible for a remote user to look up the capacity of RAM und CPU that user has

Tags: linux, remote-access

I have remote linux server account. I could use top the see the total capacity and usage of the machine, but the whole resource was not just for me. Can I somehow figure out my assigned capacity of RAM and CPU?

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 771915
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ulimit` command (specifically, `ulimit -a` to show all limits) to find what limits have been placed on resource usage for your account.  e.g.,

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 60929
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 60929
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot, btw I got this info (updates). after I typed `ulimit -a`, does it mean that I own unlimited RAM there? Then that would be weird, cause I ususally run out the RAM by small size of data like 1 GB.